# Django unable to save form trying to set user in a field

Tags: python, html, django

What I want to make, is to create a record of this class:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    OPTIONS = [
        ('1', 'Option 1'),
        ('2', 'Option 2'),
        ('3', 'Option 3'),
        ('4', 'Option 4'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(choices=OPTIONS, max_length=60)
    custom = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date = models.DateField(default=localdate)
```

Using this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i></span>
              </div>
              {{form.choice}}
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
              </div>
              {{form.custom}}
            </div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Confirm">
              </div>
          </form>
```

The form is defined in this way:

```
class orderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

The template is rendered by this view:

```
@login_required
def createOrder(request):
    date = localdate()
    form = None

    item = Menu.objects.filter(date=date)
    if item.exists():
        instance = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user,date=date)
        if instance.exists():
            return render(request,'requestMenu.html',{'note': 'We\'re preparing your meal'})
        else:
            user = Order(user=request.user)
            form = orderForm()
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = orderForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=False)
                    form.user = request.user
                    form.save()
                    return render(request,'requestMenu.html',{'note': 'You\'re order has been saved. We\'re preparing it for you. Be patient.'})
            else:
                return render(request,'requestMenu.html',{'note': 'Choose your meal'})
```

So... it supossed that Date field will come by default (already checked it, that's working good) and User will be assigned with actual logged user, after the form is completed. But then, when I go to check the records of this table, there's nothing on it.
So, what could be bad in my code? I think the problem is on the view.

Comment: can you show the form ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you write `fields = '__all__'` this means that the form will create fields for *all* of your models fields. Hence this also means that the form will *validate* all of these fields regardless that you set these values manually or they have a default. But you are only rendering two fields namely `choice` and `custom` in the form and hence `form.is_valid()` returns `False`, therefore you should specify the fields that the form should use instead of setting it to `__all__`:

```
class orderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['choice', 'custom']
```

Furthermore `form.user = request.user` would not do what you want instead change that part like so and directly modify the instance wrapped by the form:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.user = request.user
    form.save()
```

---

> **Note**: A class name should ideally be in `PascalCase` not `camelCase`, hence use `OrderForm` instead of <s>`orderForm`</s>. Also
> function names should be in `snake_case` hence use `create_order`
> instead of <s>`createOrder`</s>. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            if form.is_valid():
                my_form = form.save(commit=False)
                my_form.user = request.user
                my_form.save()
```

Try now.